# Detecting Normalization Breaking Changes in Unicode via the UCD

Tags: unicode, internationalization, unicode-string, unicode-normalization, case-folding

Unicode emphasizes that software should be as forward compatible as possible, by defaulting to treating unassigned characters as if they were a private use code point.  This works well in most cases, as most new characters do not change when normalized, case folded, etc.

However, I want to analyze normalization "breaking" changes in Unicode: characters which have properties that would result in changes when applying NFx, NFKx, casefold, or NFKC_Casefold normalization.  I'm not 100% confident in my understanding of the NFC or NFKC algorithms, and I believe that there have been some stability changes which limit the number of special cases.  I can limit my analysis to Unicode 4, 5, or even 6 if it means not having to deal with special cases.

My initial stab at this parses the XML Unicode Character Database and selects code points based on the [canonical combining class](https://unicode.org/reports/tr42/#d1e2672)) (`ccc != 0`), [NFxy quick check](https://unicode.org/reports/tr42/#d1e2789) (`NFC_QC != 'Y'`, `NFD_QC != 'Y'`, etc), and [casefolding/NFKC_Casefold](https://unicode.org/reports/tr42/#lp:d1e2850) (`CWKCF = 'Y' or CWCF = 'Y'`) properties.

Is this the best approach, or should I just be looking at the decomposition mapping and type?